# Is there a way to use list with EF Core Postgres JSON?

Tags: c#, json, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

This is possible in PG:

```cs
public class Parent
{
  [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
  //Mode 1: a column in the table
  public Child[] Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
  //Mode 2: a virtual column only existing in JSON
  public GrandChild[] GrandChildren { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChild
{
}
```

My question if there is a way to use other CLR types inline, instead of arrays, such as `List<T>`, `HashSet<T>` or even just `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`, to enable easy access and to avoid recreation of the collection each time we want to make a change, or to avoid defining a bunch of other proxy properties.

I tried setting `HasConversion` to array but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works "automatically" if you enable the [`type plugins` in `Npgsql.Json.NET`](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/jsonnet.html):

```
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.UseJsonNet();
using (var context = new MyContext(options.Options))
{
    var parent = new Parent()
    {
        Children = {
            new Child() {
                GrandChildren = {
                    new GrandChild() { Name = "A" },
                    new GrandChild() { Name = "B" }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    context.Add(parent);
    context.SaveChanges();

    foreach(var p in context.Parents.ToList()) {
        // This is just to print the whole object. You don't have to touch JSON.NET
        // yourself here, Npgsql will convert to/from .net types at 'the edges'.
        Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p));
    }       
}


// Using these definitions
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
       : base(options)
    { } 
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}
public class Parent
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
}    
public class Child
{
    public List<GrandChild> GrandChildren { get; set; } = new List<GrandChild>();
}    
public class GrandChild
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't that functionality provided with the new .NET Core `System.Text.Json`? Just curious. And BTW, do you have to attribute all `Id` columns with `DatabaseGenerated`? Isn't this interpreted by convention?

Comment: You could make your own Npgsql type plugin that uses System.Text.Json instead of Json.Net, I'm sure. Or maybe one already exists. The issue is that the database driver has to understand how to encode the field value for the database.